Cant download a file from a site with node.js backend unless from localhost no matter what
I wanted to share files with friends easily, so I decided to use my Raspi 5 as a server for a download website where you can just enter a path that should be downloaded as well as the password (that password being static and identical for all files is just a temporary solution that I didnt get rid of due to this issue). I used HTML/CSS/JavaScript for the frontend and tried to use node.js to handle the download request backend. However, I couldnt download from anywhere else than the localhost no matter what I tried.
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors'); // Import cors package
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const PASSWORD = "halflife";
const BASE_DIRECTORY = "/home/frissyn/dload/";


app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://192.168.178.5', 'http://192.168.178.92', 'https://192.168.178.3', 'https://192.168.178.3:3000'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
}));

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/download', (req, res) => {
    const { filePath, password } = req.body;

    if (password !== PASSWORD) {
        return res.status(403).send("Incorrect password.");
    }

    const resolvedPath = path.resolve(BASE_DIRECTORY, filePath);
    if (!resolvedPath.startsWith(BASE_DIRECTORY)) {
        return res.status(400).send("Invalid file path.");
    }

    fs.access(resolvedPath, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(404).send("File not found.");
        }

        res.download(resolvedPath, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send("Failed to download the file.");
            }
        });
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);

});

When trying simply app.use(cors()) to allow all routes, not even the localhost worked, depending on what I tried I got either "CORS Request did not succeed" or "CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing".
Now, with the code above, downloading as the localhost works, downloading from anywhere else doesnt.

Likely an irrelevant comment based on my looking at docs, but maybe try reordering your middleware call for cors to be after json? I don't think it matters in this case, but that is what the docs show

Share the full error, share the URL of the application making the request, share the URL where this application is running and look at the network tab and share which CORS request adn response headers are actually being sent to help debug this issue
